# Can a Javascript IF statement handle more than two conditions?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a javascript statement with 2 conditions and now want to add a third.  It seems like I have some syntax error, but want the If condition to execute if all 3 conditions are true.  Can I have more than two in an IF statement?

Original (which works fine)

```
if (
    typeof(engravingSamples) != "undefined" 
    && $("form[name='prdform'] input[name='format']").val() == "true"
)
```

New (which does not execute)

```
if (
    typeof(engravingSamples) != "undefined" 
    && $("form[name='prdform'] input[name='format']").val() == "true") 
    && $("form[name='prdform'] input[name='lines']").val() > "6"
)
```

Comment: Yes. You can add more than 2 conditions within an `if` statement. `if (true && true && true){console.log('yes')}`

Comment: You can have as many conditions as you need. Check your open and close brackets and make sure everything is correctly enclosed and you should be fine.

Comment: There's a syntax error where the third was added without accounting for the trailing parenthetical.

Comment: `val() > "6"` looks wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have one parenthesis too many in your statement, it closes after the `== "true"` and again after the  `> "6"`. That's why you have an error. One pro tip i can give you is to add line break betwen your condition, it makes them easier to read.

```
if (typeof(engravingSamples) != "undefined" 
    && $("form[name='prdform'] input[name='format']").val() == "true"
//------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
    && $("form[name='prdform'] input[name='lines']").val() > "6")
```

Also, `> "6"` does not sounds right. you are checking if something is greater than a string ? Javascript might be able to convert that, but it would be a better practice to compare integers with integers.

Answer (score 0):

As @j08691 pointed out, you're going to give yourself another bug with that ' > "6" ' condition. You'll be performing a string comparison if you're checking that way.

A string comparison means that 55 will be considered less than "6" because "6" is greater than "5" in javascript logic. Unless you're intentionally performing a string operation, you most likely want to get rid of those quotation marks and use the integer version of 6.

If you'd like to convert the user's input to an integer, you can use

`parseInt($("form[name='prdform'] input[name='lines']").val()) > 6`

Comment: I see.  That was not intentional, so I need to change as you recommended.  Thanks!